# How do I replace or remove the redhat logo placed in the activities button in the top-bar?

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, gnome

[image]

I notice there is a gnome-shell-extension to replace the activities button with a custom logo, but that's not what I need.

There is a deprecated activities configurator extension, which is not supported for the Gnome version that I'm using.

I tried replacing the logos of various resolution available in "/usr/share/pixmaps/". Couldn't get it to work. I was able to replace the boot logo, the login screen logo, but couldn't find this one.

I want the activities button to be there, and only replace or remove the redhat logo, that is placed to the left side of "Activities" text.

I use RHEL 9.2 Gnome version 40.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the target icon in "/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps". The file was named "start-here.svg". Replaced it with another icon and it worked.